# Remove a Parameter from DetailsView ItemUpdating

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, detailsview, tableadapter

Here's the setup

- I have a `DetailsView` whose `DataSource` is an `ObjectDataSource`.
- The `ObjectDataSource` has two methods, select and update, that are stored procedures defined in a `TableAdapter`.
- The `Select` stored procedure takes 1 parameter--the record id--and returns the fields populated in the `DetailsView`.
- The `Update` stored procedure takes three parameters--the record id, and two data fields.

The select process works fine.

However, when the I submit the update, I get the following error:

> `ObjectDataSource` could not find a non-generic method `Update` that has parameters: [all 21 table columns]

I am trying to only pass the (3) necessary fields to the `Update` stored procedure, but the `DetailsView` is apparently trying to update using all of the fields it received from `Select`.

I know that I can access the `NewValues` collection from `DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs`, but I don't see a way to *remove* any of the parameters so that they match the definition in the stored procedure, the `TableAdapter`, and the `ObjectDataSource`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/(S(pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3))/learn/data-access/tutorial-17-cs.aspx) can provide some insight.  As long as you specify your update method and update parameters in your datasource, this should work fine.

Comment: Okay, we're headed in the right direction. In the tutorial that Aaron linked to, I found this:

"To ensure that the ObjectDataSource invokes the [correct] UpdateProduct  overload...we need to restrict the GridView to having editable fields for just the ProductName  and UnitPrice. This can be accomplished by removing the other BoundFields and CheckBoxFields, by setting those other fields' ReadOnly  property to true, or by some combination of the two."

Comment: Now the problem is that all of the fields in my DetailsView are TemplateFields, and they have no ReadOnly property. Just removing the EditItemTemplate has not worked, and I cannot, in this case, remove the fields entirely during DetailsViewMode.Edit. So while I have a greater understanding of the process, I still have not convinced .NET to use the correct update method.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around the problem for now by simply removing the unneeded values from the `NewValues` collection in the `DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs`. However, this is not optimal, since I've added another point of failure if there are changes to the stored procedure or the form.

I'd still like to know if a `TemplateField` can be set to `ReadOnly` the way that a `BoundField` can (see comments below Aaron's answer).